# What causes the difference in this toString method?

Tags: javascript

I'm mainly interested in the Object.prototype.toString method.  Both are operating on arrays but the Object.prototype.toString does something different to the output. Why is this?

Outputs: 1, 2, 3

```
console.log([1,2,3].toString());
```

Outputs: blank

```
console.log([].toString());
```

Outputs: [object Array]

```
return Object.prototype.toString.apply([]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Because `Array.prototype.toString` is a different function to `Object.prototype.toString`.

The designers of the function decided to make Array stringification output the data in the array.