# Difference between Object.prototype.toString.call(arrayObj) and arrayObj.toString()

Tags: javascript, object, tostring

I have gone through some materials and haven't completely grasped the concept when it comes to syntax such as the following :

```
var arrObj = [1,2,3];
Object.prototype.toString.call(arrObj); //Gives "[object Array]"
arrObj.toString(); // Gives "1,2,3"
```

How are the lines 2 and 3 different? As far as I understood, both call the toString method with current object being set to 'arrObj'.

Comment: That's because you are using the `Object` prototype. It is using the array as an object. You need to use `Array.prototype.toString()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Note that [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) always returns `"[object type]"`, where *type* is some sort of native type of the object

Comment: See also [What causes the difference in this toString method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489047/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `toString` is defined in `Object.prototype`, whoever inherits `Object`, will by default get the `toString` method.

But, `Array` objects, override the default `toString` method to print the array elements as comma separated string.

`Object.prototype.toString` doesn't know what type of Object it actually deals with. So, it is intentionally kept generic and it always prints the actual type of the Object. That is why

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arrObj));
```

prints

```
[object Array]
```

which is the type of object passed. But, when you do `arrObj.toString`, you are trying to represent the array in its String form, so `toString` is overriden in `Array` objects to print the array elements as comma separated string.

That is why both the calls are different.

---

But in case of other objects, the `toString` is not overriden, so they will use the `toString` from the `Object.prototype.toString`. For example,

```
var obj = {
    1: 2
};

console.log(obj.toString());
// [object Object]
```

---

Read the MDN's example of [Overriding the default `toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Example:_Overriding_the_default_toString_method)

Answer (score 6):

`toString` is [overridden for Arrays](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2); and 
`Object.prototype.toString` is different than `Array.prototype.toString`.

To get the same result with the `call`, use it on the 'correct' method:

```
 Array.prototype.toString.call(arrObj); // Gives "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

These `.call()` methods are hacky ways to treat one type as another. For example, NodeLists, as Arrays with `Array.prototype.forEach`. When you call it as an Object it will "convert it" into an Object string

```
Array.prototype.toString.call(arrObj);
```

Works perfectly. `Object.toString()` is treating kind of weirdly. ***Imagine*** the compiler doing something like:

```
[1, 2, 3] -> { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3 }
```

That will return `[Object object]`. JavaScript, unlike other languages, will always find a way out when they're type issues.

---

If you are writing a function, you could do something like:

```
function myFunction (input) {
    window[input.constructor.name].prototype.toString.call(input);
}
```