# What's the difference between these two ways of using toString()?

Tags: javascript, tostring

As the title's saying,the below two ways of using `toString()` are returning different results,I am wondering why , because I thought the 'this' here are the same in these two , both object arr.

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
toString.call(arr) //"[object Array]"
arr.toString() //"1,2,3"
```

Comment: You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010996/difference-between-object-prototype-tostring-callarrayobj-and-arrayobj-tostrin

Answer (score 1):

`toString` as a "function" is actually `window.toString`, meaning `Object.prototype.toString`. On the other hand, `arr.toString` is `Array.prototype.toString`. Both methods are specialised to produce different output appropriate for their type.